# conditional iterators in Python: How can I pick out a particular iteration?

Tags: python, django, iterator, conditional-operator

In django templates I accomplish this with `{% if forloop.first %}` but im not sure how to do this in regular 'ole python without writing a clunky counter to count up as my conditional iterates. Is their an easy way out?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "pick out a particular iteration", but if you want test the first element of a sequence than `if sequence[0]`. It would be easier to help if you show what are you trying to do and why, cause it might be wrong approach in the first place

Comment: I've checked the django templates docs to understand better your question and I'm almost sure there's better solution in python than iteration number hack. It makes sense in template system, but not in full and beautiful language like python ;)
So if you'd like to have better answers, please describe what you're up to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the corresponding value obtained from iterating over iterable. enumerate() is useful for obtaining an indexed series ...

```
>>> for i, season in enumerate(['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']):
...     print i, season
0 Spring
1 Summer
2 Fall
3 Winter
```